# Handle 404 in Spark Java Framework with Endpoints Added at Runtime

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, url-routing, endpoint, spark-java

I'm trying to figure out how to handle 404 error in Spark Java. There have been suggested hacks using "*" endpoint by adding a GET endpoint as last route in the stack. However, this will never work when endpoints are added at runtime after the application started.

The only workaround I can think of is using Apache server to trap 404 response and redirect it back to Spark, but I rather not have the logic sitting outside the application if I have a choice.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why aren't you declaring all routes on the application boot ?

Comment: I'm writing an app framework and developers can upload a new app any time and have new endpoints automatically exposed without restart. Since there is no way to unregister a route, there is way to remove and readd the hack * route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Per from Spark Java team, there will be a feature for this in v2.5.4 available in a couple weeks.

What I ended up doing is actually routing everything to 1 endpoint (//*). Since I know all the available routes in the system, I can then check against the registry and if there is no match, I redirect it to "/404". One more thing is to setup the proxy so that "/" points to "/" with exception of some well known top level directories such as one for web assets (e.g. /resources).

With this, I'm able to support 404 pages per domain hosted on the framework.